# Assigning the outputs of fmin in scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a function of a single variable which I'd like to find the minimum value of, as well as the value of the variable where the minimum is attained. Currently I achieve this through the following Python script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import math

x1=0.
y1=800.
x2=1100.
y2=-800.

v1=2000.
v2=4000.

def T(xi):
    time=sqrt((x1-xi)**2+y1**2)/v1+sqrt((x2-xi)**2+y2**2)/v2
    return time

fmin(T,0)
```

Running this script produces the following echo:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import math

x1=0.
y1=800.
x2=1100.
y2=-800.

v1=2000.
v2=4000.

def T(xi):
    time=sqrt((x1-xi)**2+y1**2)/v1+sqrt((x2-xi)**2+y2**2)/v2
    return time

fmin(T,0)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.710042
         Iterations: 41
         Function evaluations: 82
Out[24]: array([ 301.9498125])
```

So the minimum value of the function is ~0.71 and is attained for a value of the argument of ~302. I would, however, like to assign these values as follows:

```
(Tmin,xmin)=fmin(T,0)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.710042
         Iterations: 41
         Function evaluations: 82
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Kurt.Peek\<ipython-input-25-aec613726d59> in <module>()
----> 1 (Tmin,xmin)=fmin(T,0)

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

So I get an error "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack". Does anybody know how to prevent this error and assign those two outputs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fmin` has a `full_output=True` parameter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html):

```
xopt, fopt, iter, funcalls, warnflag = fmin(T,0, full_output=True, disp=False)
print(xopt, fopt)
# (array([ 301.9498125]), 0.71004171552448025)
```

Comment: Although this seems like the right way to use fmin, I was thinking along the lines of Matlab's "varargout", in which the optional outputs have a specific order (varargout{1}, varargout{2}, etc.) and the user can assign any number of outputs depending on how many he is interested in. In this example, I'm not interested in "iter", "funcalls", or "warnflag", yet apparently I do have to create variables for them if I am to use "full_output=True". In short, it works, but seems less user-friendly than Matlab.

Comment: Suppose you had a chain of function calls they each passed their return value to each other: `f(*g(*h()))`. Wouldn't it become confusing to know what exactly is getting passed at each stage? I think the Python way leads to cleaner design.

Answer (score 0):

The following achieves the same thing: at the end of the script I added

```
xmin=fmin(T,0)
Tmin=T(xmin)
```

This yields the desired outputs:

```
xmin
Out[30]: array([ 301.9498125])

T(xmin)
Out[31]: array([ 0.71004172])
```

So instead of specifying several outputs for fmin, I got just the argument and used the function again to obtain the minimum value.